# Android: Skobbler, how to custom map tiles?

Tags: android, skmaps

As the title, i want to know if there are any way to custom the map tiles with Skobbler.

Ex:

- load my own tiles instead of default tile
- load only tiles on defined
  range

I checked the api document but it seem doesn't help! Could you help to give some hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not be possible.

The SDK uses a proprietary vector tile format (.skm) - one would have to convert their map data to this format before they are usable by the Scout SDK.

Overlaying images/tiles from an external source on top of the map is also not currently available (it's a request on the "wish list")